# AutoHotKey - Switch Shift key

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to use AutoHotKey to remap a few keys. For example:

```
;remap the 9 key to (
9::Send (

;Remap the shift 9 key to output 9. 
$+9::Send, {9} -- fails.
```

Does anyone know how to remap the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + key to the normal key?

I'd like to remap these keys to avoid pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key often. I frequently type ()_ in my code and I'd rather not have to press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key every time. With that being said, I also do not want to lose access to their default keys.

Edit 1:

Final code is as follows:

```
;remap the 9 key to (
9::(

;Remap the shift 9 key to output 9. 
$+(::Send 9

;remap the 0 key to )
0::)

;remap the shift 0 key to 0
$+)::Send 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works at my side:

```
9::(
$+(::Send 9
```

This also works, which may make clearer intention:

```
9::(
$+9::Send 9
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use my script. I replaced '[' and ']' with '(' and ')'

```
[::(
]::)
$+(::Send [
$+)::Send ]
+[::{
+]::}
```